# Rails server getting slow then crashes because of files created in public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

Lots of files with **404 file's content gets created in the public folder** of the rails app.
 
We are not sure how these files were created. 
Even the **robot.txt got replaced with content from 404 file.** 
After cleaning the public folder and restarting the server, its getting messed up again after some time. 
We couldn't keep the server up. 
Have any of you encountered this issue?. We are clueless at this point, please help us.

In my public folder files will be created automatically in the following names. so that my actual files will be replaced with 404.html content. 
 
mv2X5 
nmzrFU 
o1zU2yDFHhLkmyrJp 
o3LcsQPtrzbXY 
p7aI7 
pDBenkg1VudY5mWAJDurVrrE+UiBnkHV 
pPHiy3272niMxa 
pQRqGFrNKTjdlExRut 
php 
phpAlbum 
phpalbum 
r3tTNjfva 
robots.html 
robots.htmlmysite.in 
robots.txt

Comment: I've not seen this issue before. Can you show us your routes and also do a search through your app directory for the phrase "404" and "four_oh_four" and show us the results?

Comment: Could possibly be a routes + static caching problem. If you have a default route that caches to static files that would explain the behavior.

Comment: i added the example in my question. please go through it.